# Prove complex number relationship with triangular inequality

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

I have this math question that I'm kind of stuck on.

> Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are complex numbers.  Use the result of the
>    triangular inequality to prove that  $$ |a| - |b|
>  \le |a - b|   \hspace{5pt} \text{ and }  \hspace{5pt} - |a - b| \le |a| - |b|$$
>
> (The two inequalities can be combined together as:    $ - |a - b| \le |a| - |b| \le |a - b|$ which means
>    $\bigm|  |a| - |b| \bigm| \le |a - b|$.)

The triangular inequality $\mid z_1+z_2\mid\le \mid z_1\mid+\mid z_2\mid$

Here's what I have so far:

$$\bigm| \mid a\mid - \mid b\mid\bigm| \le \mid a-b \mid$$
$$\bigm| \mid a\mid - \mid b\mid\bigm|^2 \le \mid a-b \mid^2$$
$$\bigm| \mid a\mid - \mid b\mid\bigm|^2 = (\mid a\mid - \mid b\mid)(\overline{\mid a\mid-\mid b\mid}) = (\mid a\mid - \mid b\mid)(\overline{\mid a\mid}-\overline{\mid b\mid}) = (\mid a\mid - \mid b\mid)(\mid a\mid - \mid b\mid)$$
$$= \mid a\mid^2-\mid a\mid \cdot \mid b\mid - \mid a\mid \cdot \mid b\mid + \mid b\mid^2$$
$$= a\overline{a}-2\cdot |ab| + b\overline{b}$$

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track... but regardless, I'm stuck at this point. Thanks.

Comment: Often people use the vertical bar "|" where \mid should be used, but occasionally they use \mid where the vertical bar should be used.  This one does the latter.

Answer (score 1):

You know that

$|a+b| \leq |a|+|b|$.

Now put $a=A-B$ and $b=B$

Then $|a+b| \leq |a|+|b| \Rightarrow |A-B+B| \leq |A-B|+|B|$

That is $|A| \leq |A-B| +|B|\Rightarrow |A|-|B| \leq |A-B|$

Similarly

Put $a=A$ and $b=B-A$.

Then You will get  $|a+b| \leq |a|+|b| \Rightarrow |A+B-A| \leq |A|+|B-A|$

That is $|B| \leq |A| +|B-A|\Rightarrow |B|-|A| \leq |B-A|=|A-B|$

So $-[|A|-|B|] \leq |A-B|$

Answer (score 1):

As you have used $$|z_{1}+z_{2}|\leq |z_{1}|+|z_{2}|.........(1)$$

Now replace $z_{1}\rightarrow z_{1}-z_{2}\;,$ in $(1)$

We get $$|z_{1}-z_{2}+z_{2}|\leq |z_{1}-z_{2}|+|z_{2}|\Rightarrow |z_{1}|\leq |z_{1}-z_{2}|+|z_{2}|$$

So we get $$|z_{1}|-|z_{2}|\leq |z_{1}-z_{2}|........(2)$$

Again  replace $z_{2}\rightarrow z_{2}-z_{1}\;,$ in $(1)$

We get $$|z_{1}-z_{2}-z_{1}|\leq |z_{1}|+|z_{2}-z_{1}|\Rightarrow |z_{2}|\leq |z_{1}|+|z_{2}-z_{1}| = |z_{1}-z_{2}|+|z_{1}|$$

So we get $$|z_{2}|-|z_{1}|\leq |z_{1}-z_{2}|........(3)$$

Comment: Is this a rule? $|z_1|+|z_2−z_1|=|z_1−z_2|+|z_1|$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: replace $z_1$ with $z_1-z_2$ in the triangular inequality.